# Is it possible to make Particles follow Displacement Node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, particles, displacement

I'm faced a problem that I can't find a workaround for.

**Displacement Node and particles.**
I understand that in modifiers section of an object the particle effects have to be the last ones to make them follow the modifications, but what about Displacement Node?

I'm using multiple nodes on my setup to modify the actual displacement, so it's not possible for me to use the Displacement Modifier instead of Displacement Node.
It would be great to make Particles just follow Adaptive subdivision + true displacement but I can live with normal subivision and displacement node (I duplicate the object and use one as emitter, with normal subdivision, and second use microdisplacement).
Any workarounds to make it work?

.blend as example:
[mirror](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49919)

My mirror of this .blend:
[mirror2](http://sf.comuf.com/blender/ParticleProblem.blend)

Problem visualisation:
[image]

/edit:
Have to edit because someone marked is as duplicate:

> No, person you mentioned in link uses Displacement Modifier. There's
>   no problem with Displacement Modifier and Particles. There's problem
>   with Displacement NODE (material node), which is still in development,
>   and I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: I think I had the same issue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95183/make-particles-follow-true-material-displacement If that is the case what i did was normalize the displacement node and baked it, then used it as a texture in modifier stack

Comment: @JohanApes Can you write a guide? I'll check if that works for me.

Comment: @JohanApes I've tried baking displacement in 2.8 cycles, but the whole image is gray. Guess displacement baking does not support Displacement Node displacement. :/

Comment: Displacement Node is calculated at render time, it can't be used elsewhere outside Cycles render as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

This is a method that i used with true displacement in experimetnal 2.79

1)Use the node wrangler addon to preview the output of the displacement node

2)the values will most likeley be clamped, so you will have to **normalize them** in order to see the [0-1] range. Use **greater then** and **less then** operations to find what are the maximum and minumum values

3)Use add and divide operations using the values you got in 2) to get normalized map

4)Bake the height map (I used diffuse shader and baked colour)

5)Plug the baked height map into the displacement modifier

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
I've tried it but the Displace Modifier uses different logic than Displacement Node. Displacement Node 'Scale' is not the same as Displace Modifier 'Strength'.
I've spent about 12 hours already experimenting with that. I've used Emission node and baked emission. The baked map is good, I can use it in the Displacement Node as input instead of the original nodes, but using it in the Displace Modifier gives me different results (using UV mapping) - due to differences in Scale and Strength. :/