# Particle system does not touch the material surface

Tags: texturing, materials, particles, displacement

I have a spherical mesh and I apply some textures to displace it in order to get a rocky surface. The relevant node tree part is the following:
[image]

Keep in mind that I have turned on the bump and displacement setting.
The problem is that with this procedure the material changes the shape of the object but the mesh is not altered. As a result, the particle system previously applied touches the mesh but not the displaced material.

I have already seen this post: [Make particles follow true (material) displacement](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95183/make-particles-follow-true-material-displacement)

It says that you require an addon and that my material is an UV coordinates material. But it is not well explained how to do it. Moreover I would like to do it completely with python, and I am not sure I can do it in this way.

PS I also tried to check "Use Modifier Stack" in particle settings. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you have several options to make "real displacement" which means, that the mesh is really changed and then particle system would take these changes into account.

- use displacement modifier before particle system (you can use a voronoi texture here too)
- use geometry nodes to "make some noise" -> not much nodes needed for this
- you could use the rock generator (which ships with Blender)
- tbc...

and instead of using particle system at all i would think about using geometry nodes - because it can do a lot more than particles can.